# How do I merge two files so that equal lines do not repeat?

Tags: bash, merge

Let's say I have two files like this:

File1:
`A B C`

File2:
`D C B`

The result file should be like: `A B C D` (order doesn't matter).

I could google that up if I knew exactly the name of this mechanic (it should probably have one, to me it looks like an OR).
Using linux command `merge/cat file1 file2 > file3` outputs every single line like this `A B C D C B` but man pages of those two commands do not mention anything helpful for the purpose. I'd like to have an elegant solution like `[command] [parameter] file1 file2 > file3` since I can write a bash script to do that but it seems pretty overkill.

Comment: Questions about the site are for [meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will concatenate, then sort, then remove duplicate lines:

```
LC_ALL=C sort -u input1.txt input2.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do not need the output sorted, you can skip that step:

```
awk '{a[$0]} END {for (key in a) print key;}' file[12]
```